# Sitecore CDP triggered experience. Trigger limitations

Tags: cdp, sitecore-personalize

I have faced an issue with triggered experience:

I need to have 4 events as a trigger *(ADD, VIEW, CHECKOUT, IDENTITY)*. It works fine for any 3 events combination, but for 4 events server returns an error:

```
Error updating triggers
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

It looks like database field or backend model limitation on server side. Any suggestions/workarounds?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to bypass these limits by using Regex: `^VIEW|ADD|CHECKOUT|IDENTITY$`.

After trying many regex variations, I noticed that it only works with  `^...$` format:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example if we need to use all or one event in the list as a trigger, but I need to use all of the events together as a trigger.
something like this:

```
^(?=.*\bevent1\b)(?=.*\bevent2\b)(?=.*\bevent3\b).*$
```